# How to apply background color only for java files in eclipse?

Tags: eclipse

In Eclipse I'm able to change backgroud color, from white to blue, to all text editors from:
Preferences -> General -> Editors -> Text Editors -> Background color

But, I would change background color only for java text editors.

So for example, if I open an .xml file, background color should be white (default), instead, if I open a .java file, background color should be blue.